# Point of Intersection of tangents

Tags: geometry

Tangent are drawn to the circle $$x^2+y^2=1$$ at the point where it is met by the circles $$x^2+y^2-(\omega+6)x+(8-2\omega)y-3=0$$ where $$\omega$$  being the variable. Find the locus of point of intersection of these tangents.

Comment: What have you tried? There is not much to say about this exercise: it is simply long and tedious, but not difficult.

Comment: I suggest to make a diagram with GeoGebra, to have a better understanding and to see what the solution looks like.

Comment: @Aretino Only long and tedious if you use the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a supplement to [Marja’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2383286/265466), following the same derivation but using projective geometry methods for the calculations.

Subtracting one circle equation from the other, we get the line $$(\omega+6)x+(2\omega-8)y+2=0,$$ which we represent by the homogeneous vector $\mathbf l=[\omega+6:2\omega-8:2]$. (We could also have found this by subtracting the matrices of the two circles and extracting the line from the resulting singular matrix, but this is quicker.) The pole of the line through a pair of points on a conic is the intersection of the tangents through those points. The unit circle’s matrix is $C=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,-1)$, i.e., the equation of this circle can be written as $(x,y,1)C(x,y,1)^T=0$. This matrix is its own adjugate, so the intersection of the tangents at the points where $\mathbf l$ intersects $C$ is given by $$C^*\mathbf l=C\,\mathbf l=[\omega+6:2\omega-8:-2].$$ This line is the join of $[6:-8:-2]$ and $[1:2:0]$, which we can convert to non-parametric Cartesian form by taking their cross product, giving $[-4:2:-20]$, i.e., the line $$2x-y+10=0.$$

Comment: These is a Multi Choice Question with (MCQ) with one correct option

Comment: This is a MCQ with one correct answer              a) 2x-y+10=0 b) 2x+y-10=0 c) x+2y-10=0 d) x-2y+10=0.    I am in dilemma  whether Choice a) is correct or choice  b) is correct so please help me

Comment: @Marja You approach is correct but amd also found the answer which matches with one of the choice that i  mentioned my previous comment. The Locus of the point of intersection either is Line: 2x-y+10=0 or Line:2x+y-10=0 but not both so please help me as it has only one choice

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi You’ve been given two computations here. Work through the steps for yourself to see which one might have an error. Observe, too, that all of the choices that you’re given for answers to the question are related to each other by transposition or changes of sign, so I suspect that whoever wrote the question anticipated just that sort of error by the solver.

Answer (score 2):

The circles meet on the line $$-(\omega+6)x+(8-2\omega)y-2=0$$
which is obtained subtracting the equations of the two circles.

The normal vector to this line is $(-\omega-6,8-2\omega)$. Therefore the point on that line closer to the origin is $$\frac{2}{(\omega+6)^2+(8-2\omega)^2}(-\omega-6,8-2\omega)$$

By Pythagoras or by taking into account that this point and the intersection of the tangents are [inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Inverse_of_a_point) of each other with respect to the unit circle, the point of intersection of the tangents is this point divided by the square of its norm.

$$\frac{1}{2}(-\omega-6,8-2\omega)=\frac{1}{2}(-1,-2)\omega+(-3,4)$$

As $\omega$ moves this travels a line pointing in the direction of $(-1,-2)$ and passing through $(-3,4)$.

Comment: Eliminate $$\omega $$ we get 2x+y-10=0 which is the answer

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi Yes, you can transform the parametric form of the line into the implicit form.

Comment: You have a sign error right at the start. Otherwise, nice solution.